# Storing argument in a string for further use with \tabbing

Tags: xstring, tabbing

I have a macro that stores some strings in \step0, \step1, \step2...
I use the character "a" as a placeholder to be replaced down the line with \ = or \ > down the line (for use in the \tabbing environment). I was hoping t use the \StrSubstitute macro part of the xstring package to do the actual substitution but, obviously, I'm doing something wrong. It seems that the \textbackslash I'm using is not recognised as a \ (wrong catcode?). How can I fix that?

Here is a piece of code to show what I'm expecting and what I actually get.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\large

%%%%%% what It should do...
\begin{tabbing}
G\= = 9 \= - 2 \= × 3 \\
G\> = 9 \> - \>6 \\
G\> = \>1
\end{tabbing}

%%%%%%% what it does    
\expandafter\xdef\csname step0\endcsname{G a= 9 a- 2 a× 3} %define \step0
\expandafter\xdef\csname step1\endcsname{G a= 9 a-  a6} %define \step1
\expandafter\xdef\csname step2\endcsname{G a= aa1 } %define \step2

\def\textbuffer{
\StrSubstitute{dummy}{dummy}{\csname step0\endcsname}[\buffer] % puts \step1 in \buffer
\StrSubstitute{\buffer}{a}{\textbackslash=} \textbackslash\textbackslash %replaces "a" by \= and writes line 0

\foreach \k in {1,...,2}{
\StrSubstitute{dummy}{dummy}{\csname step\k\endcsname}[\buffer] % puts \step\k in \buffer
\StrSubstitute{\buffer}{a}{\textbackslash>}
 \ifthenelse{\k=2}{}{\textbackslash\textbackslash} %replaces "a" by \= and writes line k
 
}
}

\begin{tabbing}
\textbuffer % tries to use \textbuffer as argument to \tabbing
\end{tabbing}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `\k` as the running index of your code as `\k` is an accent macro in LaTeX and already defined. Instead use `\tmp` or something more unlikely to clash (or, if it has to be a single letter macro, use `\x` or something else not already defined).

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` from the `expl3`-programming layer instead of `xstring` functions. I've also changed your input syntax to not use multiple auxiliary macros with numeric names, but a single argument containing each line as a braced group.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \funkietab { O{a} m }
  {
    \funkiephil_replace:nnx {#1} \= { \tl_head:n {#2} }
    \tl_map_tokens:en { \tl_tail:n {#2} } { \\ \funkiephil_replace:nnn {#1} \> }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_tokens:nn { e }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \funkiephil_replace:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl {#3}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl {#1} {#2}
    \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \funkiephil_replace:nnn { nnx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%%%%%% what It should do...
\begin{tabbing}
G\= = 9 \= - 2 \= × 3 \\
G\> = 9 \> - \>6 \\
G\> = \>1
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabbing}
  \funkietab {
    {G a= 9 a- 2 a× 3}
    {G a= 9 a-  a6}
    {G a= aa1}
  }
\end{tabbing}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The following is an alternative that uses the `step<num>` notation (in fact it supports arbitrary naming schemes as long as they are numeric). The new macro takes an optional argument giving the character (sequence) that should be replaced by either `\=` or `\>` (defaulting to `a`), a mandatory argument specifying the naming scheme of the variables (using `#1` for the numeric part), an optional argument giving the first index (defaulting to `0`), and a mandatory argument specifying the last.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl
\cs_new:Npn \__funkietab_name:n #1 {}
\NewDocumentCommand \funkietab { O{a} m O{0} m }
  {
    \cs_gset:Npn \__funkietab_name:n ##1 {#2}
    \funkiephil_replace:nnn {#1} \= {#3}
    \int_step_inline:nnn { #3 + 1 } {#4}
      { \\ \funkiephil_replace:nnn {#1} \> {##1} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \funkiephil_replace:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_set_eq:Nc \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl { \__funkietab_name:n {#3} }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl {#1} {#2}
    \l__funkiephil_tmp_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%%%%%% what It should do...
\begin{tabbing}
G\= = 9 \= - 2 \= × 3 \\
G\> = 9 \> - \>6 \\
G\> = \>1
\end{tabbing}

\expandafter\xdef\csname step0\endcsname{G a= 9 a- 2 a× 3} %define \step0
\expandafter\xdef\csname step1\endcsname{G a= 9 a-  a6} %define \step1
\expandafter\xdef\csname step2\endcsname{G a= aa1 } %define \step2

\begin{tabbing}
  \funkietab{step#1}{2}
\end{tabbing}
 
\end{document}
```

Output like above.

Comment: thanks a lot. I know nothing about expl13, I guess I'm going to have to look it up.

Comment: @Skilmon It works the way you wrote it but  I need to have the numbered macros as input. I tried to replace each line with something like \csname step0\endcsname but it doesn't work.

Comment: @FunkiePhil most likely you don't need the numbered macros... But I'll make some changes.

Comment: @FunkiePhil does the second code work for you?

Comment: @Skilmon Yes it does! Thanks a lot, now I've got to understand how it works.

Comment: @FunkiePhil do you have specific questions? Skimming through the 16 pages of [`expl3.pdf`](https://texdoc.org/pkg/expl3) might give you a basic idea of what happens. For concise descriptions of the used functions search for them in [`interface3.pdf`](https://texdoc.org/pkg/interface3).